# Bare metal cross compilers input

Tags: linux, compiler-construction, mips

What are the input limitations of a bare metal cross compiler...as in does it not compile programs with pointers or mallocs......or anything that would require more than the underlying hardware....also how can 1 find these limitations..

I also wanted to ask...I built a cross compiler for target mips..i need to create a mips executable using this cross compiler...but i am not able to find where the executable is...as in there is 1 executable which i found mipsel-linux-cpp which is supposed to compile,assemble and link and then produce a.out but it is not doing so...

However the ./cc1 gives a mips assembly.......

There is an install folder which has a gcc executable which uses i386 assembly and then gives an exe...i dont understand how can the gcc exe give i386 and not mips assembly when i have specified target as mips....

please help im really not able to understand what is happ...

I followed the foll steps..
1. Installed binutils 2.19
2. configured gcc for mips..(g++,core)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you should have started two separate questions.

The GNU toolchain does not have any OS dependencies, but the GNU library does. Most bare-metal cross builds of GCC use the Newlib C library which provides a set of *syscall* stubs that you must map to your target yourself. These stubs include low-level calls necessary to implement stream I/O and heap management. They can be very simple or very complex depending on your needs. If the only I/O support is to a UART to stdin/stdout/stderr, then it is simple. You don't have to implement everything, but if you do not implement teh I/O stubs, you won't be able to use printf() for example. You must implement the sbrk()/sbrk_r() syscall is you want malloc() to work.

The GNU C++ library will work correctly with Newlib as its underlying library. If you use C++, the C runtime start-up (usually crt0.s) must include the static initialiser loop to invoke the constructors of any static objects that your code may include. The run-time start-up must also of course initialise the processor, clocks, SDRAM controller, timers, MMU etc; that is your responsibility, not the compiler's.

I have no experience of MIPS targets, but the principles are the same for all processors, there is a very useful article called ["Building Bare Metal ARM with GNU"](http://www.state-machine.com/arm/Building_bare-metal_ARM_with_GNU.pdf) which you may find helpful, much of it will be relevant - especially porting the parts regarding implementing Newlib stubs.

Regarding your other question, if your compiler is called mipsel-linux-cpp, then it is not a 'bare-metal' build but rather a Linux build. Also this executable does not really "compile, assemble and link", it is rather a driver that separately calls the pre-processor, compiler, assembler and linker. It has to be configured correctly to invoke the cross-tools rather than the host tools. I generally invoke the linker separately in order to enforce decisions about which standard library to link (-nostdlib), and also because it makes more sense when a application is comprised of multiple execution units. I cannot offer much help other than that here since I have always used GNU-ARM tools built by people with obviously more patience than me, and moreover hosted on Windows, where there is less possibility of the host tool-chain being invoked instead (one reason why I have also avoided those tool-chains that rely on Cygwin)

Comment: The "Building Bare Metal ARM with GNU" article doesn't mention Newlib. There's a likely-looking article at http://balau82.wordpress.com/2010/12/16/using-newlib-in-arm-bare-metal-programs/.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
With more time available, I have rewritten my original answer in an attempt to provide something more useful.

I cannot provide a specific answer for your question. I have never tried to get code running on a MIPS machine. What I do have is plenty of experience getting a variety of "bare metal" boards up and running. All kinds of CPUs and all kinds of compilers and cross compilers. So I have an understanding of the principles that apply in all such situations. I will point out the kind of knowledge you will need to absorb before you can hope to succeed with a job like this, and hopefully I can list some links to resources to get you started on learning that knowledge.

I am worried you don't know that pointers are *exactly* the kind of thing a bare metal compiler can handle, they are a basic machine primitive. This tells me you are probably not an expert embedded developer who is just stuck in this particular scenario. Never mind. There isn't anything magic about programming an embedded system, and you can learn what you need to know.

The first step is getting to understand the relationship between C and the machine you wish to run code on. Basically C is a portable assembly language. This means that C is good for manipulating the basic operations of the machine. In this sense the basic operations of the machine are reading and writing memory locations, performing arithmetic and boolean operations on the data read from memory, and making branching and looping decisions based on that data. In particular the C concept of pointers allows you to manipulate data at locations in memory that you specify.

So far so good, but just doing raw computations in memory is not usually enough - you need a way to input and output data from memory. To do that you need to manipulate the hardware peripherals on your board. If the hardware peripherals are *memory mapped* then the machine registers used to control the peripherals look exactly like memory locations and C can manipulate them directly. Even in that case though, it is much more likely that doing useful I/O is best handled by extending the C core language with a library of routines provided just for that purpose. These library routines handle all the nasty details (timers, interrupts, non-memory mapped I/O) involved in manipulating the peripheral hardware on the board, and wrap them up with a convenient C function call interface. The idea is that you can go simply printf("hello world"); and the library call take care of the details of displaying the string.

An appropriately skilled developer knows how to adapt an existing I/O library to a new board, or how to develop new library routines to provide access to non-standard custom hardware. The classic way to develop these skills is to start with something simple, usually a LED for an output device, and a switch for an input device. Write a program that pulses a LED in a predictable way, or reads a switch and reflects in on a LED. The first time you get this working will be hugely satisfying.

Okay I have rambled enough. It is time to provide some more resources for you to study. The good news is that there's never been a better time to learn how things work at the interface between hardware and software. There is a wealth of freely available code and docs. Stackoverflow is a great resource as you know. Good luck! Links follow;

[Embedded systems overview](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Embedded_Systems)

[Knowing the C language well is fundamental](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c%5Fbook/)

[Why not get your code working on a simulator before you try real hardware](http://www.linux-mips.org/wiki/Emulators)

[Another emulated environment](http://gavare.se/gxemul)

[Linux device drivers - an overlapping subject](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

[Another book about bare metal programming](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/)

Comment: hi....actually i am very new to this field and so im not really sure about anything but i have a few ideas....as in i generated a .s file ie compiled a .c file....i wanted to know what the gcc exe does..

Comment: @Bill :: hi also can you please suggest some reading material so i can improve my knowledge....i dont want to be spoonfed...i really want to learn....

Comment: I will try to assemble a simple reading list for you when I have time - expect another comment within the next 12 hours or so.

Comment: @Bill :: Thank you soo much..i will definitely look at all of these...and i have absolutely no experience with embedded systems at all..i am actually new to both linux and compilers(having just finished my BE..)...have been exposed to linux fr the last 2 months and compilers (cross compilers) fr the last 1 week only....so am a complete newbie...:-)...but i am really very very interested in this field and am willing to work hard n learn....thank you soo much...:-)